# Using Discord Bot To Display Youtube Video

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, pytube

I want my discord bot to send basic youtube embeds that appear automatically when a link from youtube is pasted on discord by a user.

I do know i need to install and use  **pytube** for this.

Just need some direction on how to connect my bot to youtube.
(I'm new to discord.py)

For example i do `!yt mango` and the bot sends the top 3 results that come when searched for `mango` on youtube.

Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want my discord bot to send basic youtube embeds that appear automatically when a link from youtube is pasted on discord by a user.

auto-embeds is a default functionality of Discord. When someone posts a link and you have auto-embeds enabled for the server you will be able to watch the YouTube video from the Discord client.

> I do know i need to install and use  **pytube** for this.

pytube is for downloading YouTube videos. You don't need to download the video. Thus pytube is not needed.

> Just need some direction on how to connect my bot to youtube.
> (I'm new to discord.py)

Familiarize yourself with discord.py first. Here is the manual:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

Get a basic discord bot running before attempting anything more advanced.

> For example i do `!yt mango` and the bot sends the top 3 results that come when searched for `mango` on youtube.

To be able to search on YouTube you need Google API. Refer to: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python

Here is a possible library you could use: https://pypi.org/project/python-youtube/

---

On StackOverflow we don't write code for you. We can only guide you in the direction but you have to write the actual code yourself or be more specific with your problem. Break your big problem into smaller tasks and solve those.
StackOverflow is more for debugging faulty code.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! 
That was extremely helpful :)